# Sympify of factorials in Sympy

Tags: sympy

I have the following Sympy code that works as expected:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify
from sympy.core import sympify
from sympy import factorial

ex = sympify('-x**2 / cos(x)')
flam = lambdify(['x'], ex, "numpy")
flam(np.array(range(5)))
```

This returns:

```
array([ 0.        , -1.85081572,  9.61199185,  9.09097799, 24.4781705 ])
```

Now, what I need to know is how to do the same for factorials, that is, using `factorial(x)` instead of `cos(x)`. The code:

```
ex = sympify('-x**2 / factorial(x)')
flam = lambdify(['x'], ex, "numpy")
flam(np.array(range(5)))
```

raises a `NameError`

```
NameError: global name 'factorial' is not defined
```

What string should I use so that it gets converted to a factorial that can be evaluated after `lambdify`?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By tinkering I obtain the following code. It seems that the numpy factorial function do not works with ndarrays...

```
import numpy as np
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify

flam = lambdify(['x'], '-x**2 / cos(x)', "numpy")
flam(np.array(range(5)))

# >>> array([ 0.        , -1.85081572,  9.61199185,  9.09097799, 24.4781705 ])


import scipy.special

flam = lambdify('x', 'factorial(x)', ['numpy', {'factorial':scipy.special.factorial}])
flam(np.array(range(5)))

# >>> array([ 1.,  1.,  2.,  6., 24.])
```